# Maximum volume cross-section of a hypercube

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

This is surely well known, but:

> **Q1**. What is the $(d{-}1)$-dimensional polytope
>   that realizes the maximum volume cross-section of a unit hypercube
>   by a $(d{-}1)$-dimensional hyperplane?

*Answered* in the comments: Ball's theorem.

---

[image: Hexagon]

          

<sup>(Image from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cube.html).
This is *not* the maximum area slice [Noam Elkies].)</sup>

---

I am less interested in the numerical maximum volume as I am in a description of
the polytope that achieves it.

---

[image: 4DCrossSections]

          

<sup>(4D slicing snapshots from [eusebeia.dyndns.org](http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/vis/04-xsec).)</sup>

---

> **Q2**. Is the polytope that answers Q1 is the same as
>   that which achieves the maximum volume orthogonal projection (shadow) of the hypercube?

*Answered* by Paata Ivanisvili: No for $d \ge 3$.

Comment: **Q1**: As I recall the central section orthogonal to $(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$
gives a cross-section approaching $\sqrt{6/\pi}$ for large $n$,
which is less than the $\sqrt 2$ of the central section orthogonal to
$(1,1,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$.  Certainly in dimension $3$ the hexagon
is pretty but smaller (area $\sqrt{27/16} < 1.3 < 1.4 < \sqrt2$).
That $\sqrt 2$ is supposed to be maximal but I don't know/remember
whether this has been proved.

Comment: The somewhat strange constant $\sqrt{6/\pi}$ comes from the 
Gaussian approximation to 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bigl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigr)^n \, dx$, with
$\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 - \frac16 x^2 + O(x^4)$.
 = 1 - \frac16 x^2 + O(x^4)$.

Comment: Q1: I think this has been proved, the maximal area is $\sqrt{2}$ and it is attained only if  the hyperplane has a normal unit vector  with two nonzero coordinates with absolute value $1/\sqrt{2}$
As far as I know this is Ball's theorem. Fedja wrote a simple proof once many years ago 
http://www.math.spbu.ru/analysis/f-doska/cube.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  Now I have to decide if I want to learn it enough to decipher the Russian . . . (in the title TEOREMA BOLLA = Ball's theorem, and EDINICHNOVO KUBA is presumably "unit cube", but it would take a long time to workout everything from context.)

Comment: Here is another exposition of Ball's theorem https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/pooley/upper_bounds_on_the_cross-sectional_volumes_of_cubes_and_other_problems.pdf

Comment: In a later paper Ball also proves that the volume of a codimension k slice of the hypercube is at most $2^{k/2}$, and this can be achieved whenever k is at most half the dimension of the hypercube.

Comment: @Naom D. Elkies, Yes, you are right. 

Q2. 

The volume of the projection is maximized when the normal vector to the hyperplane  has coordinates equal to each other by absolute value Then it follows that the answer to question Q2 is negative when n >2.

The volume of the shadow projected onto the hyperplane with normal vector $u=(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ is $\frac{1}{2}\sum |u_{j}|$.

Comment: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/test-your-intuition2/